# How to rename multiple Columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures, multiple-columns, rename

My goal is to get a concise way to rename multiple columns in a data frame. Let's consider a small data frame df as below:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1, b=2, c=3)
df
```

Let's say we want to change the names from a, b, and c to Y, W, and Z respectively.
Defining a character vector containing old names and new names.

```
df names <- c(Y = "a", Z ="b", E = "c")
```

I would use this to rename the columns,

```
rename(df, !!!names)
df
```

suggestions?

Comment: `rename(df, !!!names)` works fine for me. You could check you have attached `dplyr` package.

Comment: @DarrenTsai - my eyesight must be getting worse or i'm just having a bad day. I could have sworn the original question had only two `!!`'s in it.

Answer (score 2):

One more `!`:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1, b=2, c=3)
df_names <- c(Y = "a", Z ="b", E = "c")
library(dplyr)
df %>% rename(!!!df_names)
##  Y Z E
##1 1 2 3
```

A non-tidy way might be through `match`:

```
names(df) <- names(df_names)[match(names(df), df_names)]
df
##  Y Z E
##1 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
sample(LETTERS[which(LETTERS %in% names(df) == FALSE)], size= length(names(df)), replace = FALSE)
[1] "S" "D" "N"
```

Here, you don't really care what the new names are as you're using sample. Otherwise a straight forward `names(df) < c('name1', 'name2'...`